# Apply function to numpy matrix dependent on position

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Given a 2-d numpy array, X, of shape [m,m], I wish to apply a function and obtain a new 2-d numpy matrix P, also of shape [m,m], whose [i,j]th element is obtained as follows:

```
P[i][j] = exp (-|| X[i] - x[j] ||**2)
```

where `||.||` represents the standard L-2 norm of a vector. Is there any way faster than a simple nested for loop?

For example,

```
X = [[1,1,1],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

Then, at diagonal entries the rows accessed will be the same and the norm/magnitude of their difference will be 0. Hence,

```
P[0][0] = P[1][1] = P[2][2] = exp (0) = 1.0
```

Also,

```
P[0][1] = exp (- || X[0] - X[1] ||**2) = exp (- || [-1,-2,-3] || ** 2) = exp (-14)
```

etc.

The most trivial solution using a nested for loop is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
P = np.zeros (shape=[len(X),len(X)])
for i in range (len(X)):
    for j in range (len(X)):
        P[i][j] = np.exp (- np.linalg.norm (X[i]-X[j])**2)
        
print (P)
```

This prints:

```
P = [[1.00000000e+00 1.87952882e-12 1.24794646e-47]
    [1.87952882e-12 1.00000000e+00 1.87952882e-12]
    [1.24794646e-47 1.87952882e-12 1.00000000e+00]]
```

Here, m is of the order of 5e4.

Comment: @j1-lee actually no, X[i] represents a 1-d vector

Comment: Fro clarity's sake give us  a working example, with the nested loop if necessary.  Then take some time to read up on `numpy` `broadcasting`.

Comment: @hpaulj I just gave the working code of a trivial implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hpaulj mentioned cdist does it better. Try the following.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

np.exp(-cdist(X,X,'sqeuclidean'))
```

Notice the `sqeuclidean`. This means that scipy does not take the square root so you don't have to square like you did above with the norm.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [143]: X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
     ...: P = np.zeros (shape=[len(X),len(X)])
     ...: for i in range (len(X)):
     ...:     for j in range (len(X)):
     ...:         P[i][j] = np.exp (- np.linalg.norm (X[i]-X[j]))
     ...: 
In [144]: P
Out[144]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 5.53783071e-03, 3.06675690e-05],
       [5.53783071e-03, 1.00000000e+00, 5.53783071e-03],
       [3.06675690e-05, 5.53783071e-03, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

A no-loop version:

```
In [145]: np.exp(-np.sqrt(((X[:,None,:]-X[None,:,:])**2).sum(axis=2)))
Out[145]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 5.53783071e-03, 3.06675690e-05],
       [5.53783071e-03, 1.00000000e+00, 5.53783071e-03],
       [3.06675690e-05, 5.53783071e-03, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

I had to drop your `**2` to match values.

With the `norm` applied to the 3d difference array:

```
In [148]: np.exp(-np.linalg.norm(X[:,None,:]-X[None,:,:], axis=2))
Out[148]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 5.53783071e-03, 3.06675690e-05],
       [5.53783071e-03, 1.00000000e+00, 5.53783071e-03],
       [3.06675690e-05, 5.53783071e-03, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

In one of the `scikit` packages (learn?) there's a `cdist` that may handle this sort of thing faster.

Comment: Is the space complexity of the above approach O(m^3)?

Comment: Even with just m = 4e3, I get the following memory error: numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 93.5 GiB for an array with shape (4000, 4000, 784) and data type float64. Any other solution? :(

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier if you provided a sample array.  You can create an array Q of size [m, m, m] where Q[i, j, k] = X[i, k] - X[j, k] by using

```
X[None,:,:] - X[:,None,:]
```

At this point, you're performing simple numpy operations against the third axis.

Comment: But m is of the order of 5e4. I have now provided an example.